# Leaving out Data based on Checking 2 fields for null

Tags: t-sql

I have a query and at the end I want to leave out records where a certain two fields contain nulls at the same time

e.g.

```
and ((d.status is null AND b.actual is null)) < 1
```

so basically leave out the record if both of these fields have null at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write this as:

```
...WHERE d.status IS NOT NULL OR b.actual IS NOT NULL
```

which, by [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), could also be written as:

```
...WHERE NOT(d.status IS NULL AND b.actual IS NULL)
```